# How to make a figure with code?

Tags: graphics, listings

I am able to add code to a Latex document with the `listings` package. Here's some simple code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings} 
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Mathematica,caption={Simple Code}]
f1 = Cos[2*Pi*freq1*t]; 
freq = 1 + 2*t;
f2 = Cos[2*Pi*Integrate[freq, t]*t];
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

However, there is a problem. My thesis can only include only figures or tables. From my university's formatting guidelines:

> Do not use any designation other than Figure or Table ... in the manuscript

So I want to have beautifully formatted code, but it should be "Figure 3.4" or whatever.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap the code listing in a figure environment as demonstrated below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} 
\begin{document}

See Figure~\ref{code.1} for my code.

\begin{figure}[hbtp]
    \caption{Code}
    \label{code.1}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=Mathematica,frame=single]
        f1 = Cos[2*Pi*freq1*t]; 
        freq = 1 + 2*t;
        f2 = Cos[2*Pi*Integrate[freq, t]*t];
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works

Comment: Just be careful not to use the `float` or `caption` options.

Comment: im having 2 problems with this code: the referencing does not work for me and this box is not included. how do i add a box?

Comment: @Britta:  Hi, I added "frame=single" to the lstlisting environment.  I also added an example line demonstrating how to reference the figure.  Hopefully that helps you.

Comment: @James, thanks for the quick reply. Ive tried it but it sadly doesn't help. I keep getting Figure ?? in my code, which is so strange...

Comment: @Britta:  It works for me, but you have to compile more than once for LaTeX to resolve the references.  So from the command line, I compile twice.  After only one compile, you'll see the ??.  My apologies if you already knew that but are experiencing a more complex issue.

Comment: @James: I tried recompiling it but it hasn't worked for me. I'm using overleaf, that might make a difference. I'll try to figure something else out. Thanks anyways !

Comment: @Britta: I've never used Overleaf, so I'm not sure if there is a simple fix.  You might start a new question.  Show my code above and show an image of your output with the "??".  State that the code works in LaTeX (link to this question), but not in Overleaf.  Good luck!